# Load data from Vertica DB to a file using Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vertica

Basically, I'm looking for the fastest way to load very large data sets to a dataframe. 
I understand that first loading a table from Vertica to a file can help. 
Currently saving the data to a CSV from the DB IDE and then load the file to pandas is much faster than using pd.read_sql directly from Vertica. but the process is not convenient.

Any suggestions? 
I found this, but not sure how to use it to save to a file:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.copy("COPY test_copy (id, name) from stdin DELIMITER ',' ",  csv)
```

Would be happy to know also what is the bottleneck in the process.

Thanks!